# [Matlab]Where can I download this folder docroot\toolbox\eml\gs\examples\sl_kalman

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I am following this Matlab [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/eml/gs/bslqab6-1.html#bslqab6-3).

But I could not find the tutorial file in my computer, which is supposed to be in

> docroot\toolbox\eml\gs\examples\sl_kalman

Where can I download these files on internet?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copying Files Locally](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/eml/gs/bslqac6-1.html#bslqaef-1) should provide you with the necessary tools. Calling  `cd(docroot)` from the command line will change your current directory to *docroot*. From there on navigate to the desired location.

Keep in mind, that your referenced tutorial is for release 2010b. Possibly file locations may change between releases. Check the [Archived MathWorks Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) for your MATLAB version.